# Setting the location of WPF window dynamically when we change the screen resolution from low to high

Tags: c#, wpf

When we change screen resolution the WPF window not showing on proper location(Bottom Right).

1.Change screen resolution from high to lower value.
2.Open the WPF window.
3.Again change screen resolution from low to high.

The window will not display on proper location it is going Up .
I want it to again at bottom right.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: could you post some screen of what do you see and where do you want to see your window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to move the window after resolution change using your own code I believe, something like this:

```
window.Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - window.Width;
window.Top = = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - window.Height;
```

Check this post to see, how to detect screen resolution change

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc2f6dfa-f22c-477e-b3a5-54a088176932/detecting-screen-resolution-change

So the whole code would be like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;
    }

    void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - this.Width;
        this.Top = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - this.Height;
    }
}
```