# Positioning a Popup as "Bottom Right" to its PlacementTarget when DPI is 200%

Tags: c#, wpf

I have searched around quite extensively and cannot seem to come up with an answer to this. Most solutions I have found are a variation of adjusting the position of the popup (either in xaml or in the code behind) based on the ActualWidth and/or ActualHeight of the target control. However, none of these solutions seem to work when you change the DPI on the machine from 100%. Currently I am doing this which works perfectly as long as you do up the DPI from 100%. Is there another solution that works regardless of the DPI?

```
        <Popup x:Name="popup_search" IsOpen="False" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Left"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnShowFindPopup}"
           HorizontalOffset="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnShowFindPopup}"
           VerticalOffset="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=btnShowFindPopup}"
           Opened="popup_search_Opened">
```

EDIT TO ADD Screen Shots:

Popup at 100% and 200% DPI

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found [an answer that addresses handling a screen resolution change](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24818495/424129); the next step would be to expose some kind of property on the viewmodel that can be used in triggers in the view to reorganize things when the change happens. Maybe `enum Resolution { Low, Normal, High }`, something like that.

Comment: This is not a problem that occurs only when the DPI is changed while the application is running (if it were that I would mark it as 'known issue' and tell the users to bad, restart windows like you are supposed to do. The problem is this doesn't work AT ALL when the DPI is set to to 200%.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Does the popup not appear at all? Does it appear in the wrong place? Can you include a screenshot at 100% and another at 200%?

Comment: @MatthewSanford just to be totally clear, if the user restarts after the DPI change, the issue still persists? I've tested our apps after DPI changes, and restarting/logging out fixes the popup placement (it's required). Also the screenshots don't look DPI related, but they look related to left-handed mode. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.menudropalignment(v=vs.110).aspx